# SQL Server SELECT SUM Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help! I'm in need of assistance.

I'm trying to create a SQL Server statement; the OUTPUT is the total sum amount for New Items (1+2) and RENEW (3+4+5+6).  The total sum amount for "NEW_SUM" will sum until it hits the value "RENEW".

Table:

| ITEM | DETAIL | Detail_Type | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | ABC01 | NEW__SUM | $1 |
| 1234 | ABC02 | CONT__SUM | $2 |
| 1234 | ABC03 | RENEW_SUM | $3 |
| 1234 | ABC04 | CONT__SUM | $4 |
| 1234 | ABC05 | CONT__SUM | $5 |
| 1234 | ABC06 | CONT__SUM | $6 |

Desired output:

| ITEM | Detail_Type | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | NEW__SUM | $3 |
| 1234 | RENEW_SUM | $18 |

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Explain the logic.  (3) SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  If the processing requires an ordering, a column needs to contain the ordering.

Comment: Your ordering column really needs to be an integer only - what happens when you get to ABC99 then ABC100...?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You seem to want to group rows, based on the ordering in `DETAIL`.  The the group start with non-`'CONT'` values.  If so, just use window functions and aggregation:

```
select item,
       max(case when detail_type <> 'CONT' then detail_type end) as detail_type,
       sum(amount)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when detail_type <> 'CONT' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by item order by detail) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by item, grp;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I actually need to sum all the amounts/rows starting with "NEW_SUM" detail_type until the detail_type is "RENEW_SUM".  Once the detail type reaches "RENEW_SUM" start sum all the amounts/remaining rows.  So, the output have two sums/rows.  1st row for "NEW_SUM"; 2nd row for "RENEW_SUM".